# How can I change an image with onclick() & if statement repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, if-statement

I am new to javascript and need some help with an issue.

I have 3 traffic light images that I want to change with each click. Go from green to amber with one click, then amber to red with another click, then from red to green, etc.

I have some code below, but it seems to go from green to red with the first click.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="nextLight()">Click here</button>

<img id="demo" src="green.png">

<script>

function nextLight() {
    var lights = ["blank.png", "green.png", "amber.png", "red.png"]
    if (document.getElementById("demo").src == lights[1]) {
        document.getElementById("demo").src = lights[2];
    } else if (document.getElementById("demo").src == lights[2]) {
        document.getElementById("demo").src = lights[3];
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you assigned the click handler twice. Nevertheless, you should make yourself comfortable with "finite state machines" and how to implement those. FSMs fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the lights array as the possible states. All you need is to iterate between them.

There is a problem with the time it takes to load the amber and red images for the 1st time, as they are loaded only when the state changes. I've added a little preloader to solve that problem.

[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/8d99g6ny/5/) - note that I use other images in the demo

```
var demo = document.getElementById("demo"); // get the demo element and cache it
var lights = ["green.png", "amber.png", "red.png"]; // array of lights srcs
var currentLight = 0; // current light index holder 

lights.forEach(function(src) { // image preloader
   new Image().src = src;   
});

function nextLight() {
    currentLight++; // add one to currentLight index
    currentLight > 2 && (currentLight = 0); // if it's above 2 change it back to 0
    demo.src = lights[currentLight]; // assign the url to the src
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, i think this way is much easier :

```
var lights = ['', '', '', ''];
var currentLight = 0;

// This version will loop (Go from red to blank at the end)
function nextLight() {
   currentLight = (currentLight + 1) % lights.length;
   document.getElementById("demo").src = lights[currentLight];
}

// This version do what you want (no loop, just display each image and then do nothing)
function nextLight() {
  // Test if the next is not out of range
  if(currentLight + 1 < lights.length - 1) {
     document.getElementById("demo").src = lights[++currentLight];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `switch` statement:

```js
function nextLight() {
    var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
    var lights = [
        "",                               // blank
        "http://i.imgur.com/oisXdU3.png", // green light
        "http://i.imgur.com/qmwYgq7.png", // orange light
        "http://i.imgur.com/fs6Rl1W.png"  // red light
    ];
    
    switch(demo.src){
     case lights[1] : demo.src = lights[2]; break;
        case lights[2] : demo.src = lights[3]; break;
        case lights[3] : demo.src = lights[1]; break;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="nextLight()">Click here</button>

<img id="demo" src="http://i.imgur.com/oisXdU3.png" height="100">
```